# Reviewing Flagged Posts gone?

Tags: support, 10k-tools

Have we (read: users at the $\approx14000$ reputation point) lost the ability to review flagged posts?  I can no longer find the separate review tools for those.

Comment: I think there may just currently be no reviewable flags. The "Tools" link is still present on the "Review" page.

Comment: @DanielFischer I haven't actually seen a flag in a few weeks, though.

Comment: @DanielFischer I also can't find any reference to flags in those tools, although the tools are still present.

Comment: Aha. Then probably something changed. I don't know what, though.

Comment: There have been some changes recently. Take a look at [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228861).

Comment: @robjohn Thanks!  I knew there had to be SOMETHING... but for the life of me, I couldn't find it.

Comment: @NicholasR.Peterson I wondered the same. I browsed through meta, but couldn't find anything.